# Weak convergence of law of scaled biased random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence, wiener-measure

Let $(X_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables of finite mean $m$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Set $S_0=0$ and $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the linear interpolation $(S_t)_{t\geq0}$ given by $$S_{n+t}=(1-t)S_n+tS_{n+1}$$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $t\in[0,1]$. Set $S_t^{(N)}=N^{-1}S_{Nt}$ and write $\mu_N$ for the distribution of $(S_t^{(N)})_{t\geq0}$ on $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$. Show that the sequence $(\mu_N)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly on $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ and determine its limit.

My thoughts: I expect that Donsker's Invariance Principle is expected to be used here, but this (as far as my lectures have taught) is for random walks with steps of zero mean. This on the other hand is a biased random walk, and additionally the scaling is not as it is in Donsker's principle (the process for convergence to wiener measure is $(N^{-1/2}S_{Nt})_{t\geq0}$, so I am quite unsure of how to proceed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think here (unless there is a typo), since you are looking at the process $$\frac{1}{N} S_{Nt}= \frac{Nt}{N}\frac{1}{Nt} S_{Nt}$$
you will not need any "big guns" like Donsker's theorem or the CLT. For each fixed $t$ not zero (if $t=0$ then $S_0=0$) $S_t^{(N)}$ is tending a.s. to $mt$ by the strong law of large numbers. It also holds that for any $t_1,...,t_K\in [0,\infty)$, $(S_{t_1}^{(N)},....,S_{t_K}^{(N)}) \to (m t_1,...,m t_K)$ a.s.. So the finite dimensional distributions of the process all converge to $m t$. The only remaining thing to show in view of Prohorov's theorem is tightness of the process $S_t^{(N)}$. How would you show that?

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. As far as I'm aware, I don't think it is possible to show tightness of the process $(S_t^{(N)})_{t\geq0}$ as we don't know the distribution of the $X_i$? My knowledge of this area is poor however and I could well be wrong.

Comment: My thinking was that perhaps from here, your SLLN argument implies that for any bounded continuous function $F$ on $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$, we have that $|F((S_t^{(N)})_{t\geq0})-F((mt)_{t\geq0})|\to0$ almost surely and then the integrals converge by bounded convergence, implying weak convergence of the laws. Is this correct, and have I missed out any key justifications? Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: You don't need to know the distribution in general to establish tightness. I think you are also on the right track though with your argument: any argument here will amount to trying to show when pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence. Notice in your argument, the crux will be showing that (since $F$ is continuous w.r.t. the uniform norm on $C[0,\infty)$) that $\sup_t |S_t^{(N)} - mt| \to 0$. This is where you will be needing that the variance is finite (notice that pointwise convergence to $mt$ only requires the mean is finite).

Comment: Brilliant thank you. Am I correct in thinking that it is sufficient to show that, for any fixed $T>0$ we have that $\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}|S_t^{(N)}-mt|\to0$? Sorry for all the questions - but where does the finite variance come into play? Perhaps from a Markov bound?

Comment: You will need that $\sup_{t \in [0,\infty)}|S_t^{(N)} -mt| \to 0$, but of course the aim is to reduce to a bounded interval. Notice for each fixed $N$, there is a $T$ so that $ P( \sup_{t \ge T} | S_{Nt}/(Nt) - m | > \epsilon) \le \delta$. Using this only need  $\sup_{t \in [0,T)}|S_t^{(N)} -mt| \to 0$. We already know $S_t^{(N)}$ converges pointwise. The missing ingredient then is ``equicontinuity" (see Arzela Ascoli). This amounts to showing $\sup_{|t-s| < \delta}||S_t^{(N)}-mt - (S_s^{(N)}-ms)|$ converges uniformly (over $N$) to 0 as $\delta \to 0$. This is where the variance is handy!